# variable assignment to other variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I create a different list that should have the same values as `arr` by assigning `arr` to `arr2`:

```
arr2 = arr
```

I assumed that `arr` and `arr1` are different variables.

But when I perform a `pop` action on either one of those lists, the other list gets affected too.

What is the best way to approach this problem if I don't want to hard code values into a variable that should have the values of an already existing variable?

```
>>> arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
>>> arr1 = arr 
>>> arr.pop(0) 
>>> print(arr) 
[2, 3, 4, 5] 
>>> print(arr1) 
[2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: arr=[1,2,3,4,5]
arr1=arr
arr.pop(0)
print(arr)
[2,3,4,5]
print(arr1)
[2,3,4,5]

Comment: *"I create a different list"* - no, you don't. You have two identifiers referencing the same list object. See e.g. https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: got the answer from the following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list

Answer (score -1):

```
import copy
arr1 = copy.copy(arr)
```

Now if you change anything in `arr`, it won't affect `arr1` and vice versa.